# .htaccess if directive

Tags: .htaccess

in .htaccess I have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/out\/pictures\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ core/utils/getimg.php
```

I want to change it to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/out\/pictures\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
if url == www.mysite.com {
  RewriteRule (\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ core/utils/getimg.php
} else {
  RewriteRule (\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ core/utils/getimg1.php
}
```

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think it's necessary to split this out into two:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/out\/pictures\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ core/utils/getimg.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/out\/pictures\/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ core/utils/getimg1.php
```

I've not tested this - so your mileage may vary!

Comment: Top stuff - glad it worked. Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Magic, thanks (I appear to be playing the reputation game tonight!) :)